# Clipboard copy with formatting in Kotlin/JS

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I am working on a Kotlin multiplatform project.
I want to support copy action with formatting.
There are a plenty of page in the web implementing it in javascript. All of them are almost same and do it like this:

```
const content = "SOMETHING!"
const clipboardItem = new
        ClipboardItem({
               'text/html':  new Blob([content],{type: 'text/html'}),
               'text/plain': new Blob([content],{type: 'text/plain'})
    });
    navigator.clipboard.write([clipboardItem])
```

But I don't know how should I implement it in Kotlin. Indeed, I could not construct an instance of `ClipboardItem`. How should I do it?

The following is my incomplete snippet written in Kotlin:

```
navigator.clipboard.write(
            arrayOf(
                ClipboardItem(  ..... ) // <--- What should be here?
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create an instance yourself. There is already one available for you under Window class. You can access it using **window.navigator**. Here's more about the subject https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator

Comment: Could you please give me an example in Kotlin?

Comment: window.navigator.clipboard.writeText( -text to be copied-)

Comment: This method copies the given string in a single format. I want to copy a piece of rich text in several formats like plain, html, rtf and etc.